# JQuery selector for a non-option element with attribute named "selected" in IE8-IE9

Tags: jquery, attributes, selected

Well I have an html table with some TRs something like these bellow

```
<tr id="myId" class="aRandomClass" selected="TRUE">...</tr>
<tr id="myId2" class="aRandomClass" selected="FALSE">...</tr>
```

and there is a simple selector

```
var a=$("#"+tableId).find("[selected='TRUE']");
or
var b=$("#"+tableId + " tr[selected='TRUE']");
```

which **in Firefox returns the TRs with selected='TRUE' but in MSIE 8-9 it returns nothing.** I guess the problem is that the attribute "selected" is not supposed to be used by TRs and IE finds it invalid or something like this.. but the code bellow returns the value of the attribute selected..

```
var c=$("#" + tableId + " tr").first().attr('selected');
```

There is also something noticeable that this code works with JQuery 1.4.2 also in IE. By upgrading to JQuery 1.8.3 it works only in FF.

Changing the name of the attribute is a solution that I would like to avoid for some reasons.

The solution that I have in mind is a loop "for each tr, if selected='true' add tr in var a".
Is there a better suggestion?

Comment: why use invalid attribute? Cannot you set your specific attribute instead? And of course, IDs must be unique on context page

Comment: Unfortunately the project is written by someone else, and I am responsible now for maintaining it. The "selected" attribute is used in few hundred places in java,xml,xslt and js. Change it will require a lot..

Answer (score 1):

First you have duplicate IDs which should be unique. Secondly you can select rows with `tr[selected="true"]`'

And instead of that attribute you should use `data-selected` so you have a valid markup.

Comment: The duplicate id was only false in the example. 

The selector that you suggest is not working, as I wrote above, and that is exactly the problem that I have

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest to use .prop() instead with jq 1.8.3, but really not sure it can help you here:

```
var $trsSelected = $("#"+tableId).find('tr').filter(function(){return $(this).prop('selected')=='TRUE'});

var $trsNotSelected = $("#"+tableId).find('tr').filter(function(){return $(this).prop('selected')!='TRUE'});
```

Comment: This solution works but it needs a check

$("#"+tableId).find('tr').filter(function(){
   return ($(this).prop('selected') == 'TRUE')
});

The attribute selected contains a String and should be checked as a string and not as an Boolean.